# Comment entry field has shifted to the left

Tags: bug, comments, design

I know there's some behind the scenes work being done on the comments... I think this may be related to that... I'm pretty sure that the comment entry field used to align with the comments but now it's shifted to the left and, as you can see, there's blank padding on the right where it had been.

[image: Shifted comment entry field]

I'm guessing that this isn't by design but I could be wrong.

Comment: Also noticed this today in Edge.